# How to integrate chrome browser built in tools (specifically "find") when trying to develop an extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, replace

I am trying to develop a chrome extension that part of it will need to have the global find keyword functionality, just like the built in "Find" (**Ctrl+F**) that comes with the browser. **(EDIT:** It needs to invoke "Find" multiple times and concurrently on the same tab)

My first thought is to find an API that can provide the "find" functionality from Chrome. However, after going through the [list](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index.html), I don't see what I am looking for. Also, the keywords for my question ("Chrome extension", "Chrome API","find","search") are too generic, I can not find similar examples or information for such an API even after extensive googling.

In order to provide consistent user experience I would love to provide similar, if not exact, "Find" tool in my extension. In order to avoid reinventing the wheel, it would be best if I can somehow invoke the built-in function. [Existing extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/find?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) are mostly an own implementation in Javascript with limitations (cannot search inside iframe, do not have global highlight, etc.) This will be my last resort.

Does anyone know of such an API(**that will invoke built-in "find" tool from the browser**) or a similar example to my question? If not, please let me know what's the best way to implement it in javascript, as I am new to lexical analysis or parsing.

Many Thanks!!

-Gavin

P.S: This is my first post here, if I haven't given enough information on my question (or you don't think this is a question at all), feel free to let me know!

**EDIT2:** I am trying to build an improvement extension based on "Find" that can solve this scenario:

In a text-intense page, if I want to locate a region where it mentions **keywordA** and **keywordB** but these two keyword are not immediately adjacent to each other and both of them appear many times in the document. In this case I can neither search "**keywordA keywordB**" (because they are not next to each other) nor individual keywords (too many occurrence).

For example, in an html-based math textbook, you want to locate a chapter that mentions "**linear algebra**" and "**matrix**" together the most times.

Comment: It's not clear enough what is your requirement. For example, I have a web page inside my extension and "Find" (Ctrl+F) works there perfectly well. What do you mean at "**global** find keyword functionality"?

Comment: @Stan Maybe I am unclear about that. I would like _my extension_ to  perform the "Find" functionality instead of using the built-in one. Basically I want to call "Find" **multiple times** and **concurrently** on the same tab and the native "find" doesn't support that. Thanks!

Comment: It seems impossible right now. The built in search does not support multiple concurrent invocations on the same tab. Also it's still not clear, what do you want to accomplish. Perhaps, if you could be more specific, it'll be easier to answer. Did you consider using jQuery for searching text, for example: `var search_i = $('*:contains("text to find")')`?

Comment: @Stan, that is exactly what I am trying to build: **multiple concurrent searchs on the same tab**. It seems like I cannot invoke a search from an extension and I will have to write my own version of the search. What you mention will be a good starting point for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built in search does not support multiple concurrent invocations on the same tab. So even if it becomes accessible via API some day, it's unlikely to support concurrency, because concurrent searches are not natural for general use case with a single interactive user, and involves UI. One thing that I can imagine as improvement for existing built in search is support of a query language, which will allow searching for alternatives (i.e. `car | auto` for `OR`-ing), and this would somehow address "multiple" part of your requirement.

Your option is to use a content script for searching text, for example (with jQuery):

```
var search_i = $('*:contains("text to find")');
```

This way you can perform and combine as much searches as you want, but you'll need to design a proper (understandable) UI, presenting results for every search without interference with other searches.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The reason why I want multiple concurrent search is to solve specific scenarios: In a text-intense page, if I want to locate a region where it mentions _keywordA_ and _keywordB_ but these two keyword are not immediately adjacent to each other and both of them appear many times in the document. In this case I can neither search "_keywordA keywordB_" (because they are not next to each other) nor individual keywords (too many occurrence).

Comment: This is apparently a subject for custom development. The suggested approach should work ok, though it requires coding. Look at the [javascript implementation of a fulltext index](http://karussell.wordpress.com/2010/11/02/jsii-full-text-search-in-1k-loc-of-javascript/).

Comment: Yeah, I think I will implement my own version of searching instead of trying to invoke the native search tool. Thanks for the link.